# Merging multiple raw audio files into new audio file in java (Android Studio)?

Tags: java, android, audio, merge

I want to merge multiple (2 or more, depends on the user) raw audio files into one and save that file locally. This is my code for saving a single raw audio to .mp3 locally with InputStream, but wasn't able to find a solution for using InputStream for multiple files.

```
    String filePath = requireActivity().getFilesDir().getPath();
    InputStream inputStream;
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream;
    File file = new File (filePath, "word.mp3");

    try {
        inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.allah_f_ca);
                fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            fileOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        inputStream.close();
        fileOutputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried? If so, what is the problem with your attempt?

Comment: I have tried using Sequence Input Stream but with that I'm limited to only 2 raw files, besides that I haven't tried anything else.